# I need to run a script to pull repo. from github without asking me a password

Tags: centos, bash, git, github

I just got a new server for my website, and I'm trying to create a trunk in a folder where i can pull data from github.
That way I can easily get the latest version of the website, and copy the needed files to my www.

Git works fine, but then each time I do a:

```
git pull origin master
```

It asks me for a password! I want to be able to update git via a script, or even via PHP later on. So that I can update my server automatically.
I've spend a few hours trying to figure out how to save the password but I couldn't, this is why I need your help.

I have followed a few instructions here:
http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/ 
But it didn't work.

I am SSHing from Windows to my machine using Putty. The server is a CentOS.

Now that I have added the script in ~/.bashrc as the tutorial told me to do, each time I connect with Putty I have a new line saying:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Comment: one thing i did find, if I write this in Putty:
`exec ssh-agent bash`
it asks me for the password, and doesn't ask until I restart Putty. The problem is when I restart it forgets it, and also if I would like to run this with another program (PHP) it wouldn't work.

Comment: is this a private github repository or public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). You can automatically supply the password to git through an automation script.

Just make sure your script has tight permissions -having plaintext passwords in scripts is usually *Bad Idea™*.

**Edit:**

*Since I can't write code properly in the comment section below, you could write something like this:*

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
set password "<your-password>"
spawn /usr/bin/git pull
expect "<exact passphrase>"
send "$password\r"
```

Comment: expect was something i tried using too but It didn't work.

This is how I did it:
`yum install expect (on centos)`
(it installed stuff and worked)

And then in my batch script after `git pull` I entered `expect "Enter passphrase...:` (don't remember the exact phrase), and then entered: `send: "mypassword"`. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Check again the edited the answer.

Comment: Ok so I've modified my file `update.sh` to look like this:
`#!/usr/bin/env expect
set password "wei534kfer3"
spawn /usr/local/bin/git pull origin master
expect "Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':"
send "$password\r"`

I then executed: `expect update.sh`

It shows something like that in my bash:
`
spawn /usr/local/bin/git pull origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': [root@u15927644 trunk]#` (in almost a single line), and does not execute the pull request :(. No error.